# Matched REGEXP pattern in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, regex

Imagine that there is clicks table which contains users clicks. Now I want to select the total clicks per social network:

**UPD:** refererHost column contains any referer host, not only social network host.

```
    SELECT
        c.refererHost as referer,
        COUNT(c.id) as clicks
    FROM clicks c
    WHERE c.referrerHost REGEXP 'facebook|google|linkedin'
    GROUP BY referer
    ORDER BY clicks desc
```

But the problem is that referer field will contain domain name like www.facebook.com, and I need to select matched regexp value (e.g. 'facebook'). Is it possible to do it with MySQL?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. As per documentation "Returns 1 if expr matches pat; otherwise it returns 0." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html

Comment: you can use REGEX_SUBSTR. SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR("http://theDomain/www.facebook.de",'facebook|google|linkedin'); It return only the names.

Comment: @BerndBuffen That's an Oracle SQL function.. I don't think there is an equivalent for MySQL I'm afraid

Comment: its also in MariaDB 10.0.11. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/regexp_substr/

Comment: @BerndBuffen Cool, thanks for the tip!

Comment: You need a column that means "social network", and not have to deduce it from some other column.  This should be computed when you first insert the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, I'd get rid of REGEXP entirely and go with:

```
  SELECT CASE 
           WHEN c.referrerHost LIKE '%facebook%' THEN 'facebook' 
           WHEN c.referrerHost LIKE '%google%'   THEN 'google' 
           WHEN c.referrerHost LIKE '%linkedin%' THEN 'linkedin'
         END referrer,
         COUNT(c.id) as clicks
    FROM clicks c
   WHERE c.referrerHost LIKE '%facebook%'
      OR c.referrerHost LIKE '%google%'  
      OR c.referrerHost LIKE '%linkedin%' 
GROUP BY referer
ORDER BY clicks desc
```

I'm fairly certain you'll get better performance, but you can benchmark if need be.

---

Ideally, however, I'd be tempted to build a proper referral system with a table:

- referer - id, host, title
- click   - id, referrer_id

You can work out the referral on entry to your site, easily configured with a referrer_id if you control the urls.

Then your SQL becomes:

```
  SELECT r.title as referer,
         COUNT(c.id) as clicks
    FROM clicks c
    JOIN referrer r
      ON r.id = c.referrer_id
GROUP BY referer
ORDER BY clicks desc
```

Comment: One problem I faced with: I have "referer" field in the database, so group by grouped by original field, not by resulted referer field by CASE...END statement. Renaming field to "ref" helped me.